# How to autoremove the .TMP files from project directory MVS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

MVS creates .TMP files in the project i'm working on and it does not delete them , i have searched on the web but i couldn't find a reason for that, regarding that when i edit the same classes on another computer it does not create these temp files.can any one tell me the reason for these temp files creation and how to autodelete them ?

Comment: Did you install any special add-ons for Visual Studio?

Comment: I installed a memory profile program before but i uninstalled it.

Comment: Sounds like the TEMP environment variable isn't set in your system environment.  Ask for help with that at superuser.com

Comment: Do you think uninstalling the Vs and re-installing it will fix the problem?